# wso2-am Simple pass through endpoint

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How do I create a simple pass-thru endpoint in WSO2 APIM 2.1 
to allow GET requests to access files from a given directory on my backend host.

e.g.: 
The files on my backend server are at https://192.168.10.10/javascripts/api/

When I create an WSO2 API it requires an api context and version.

I can create an API definition with:

- context: /javascripts
- version: api
- production url: https://192.168.10.10/
- verb: GET
- resource=path: /javascripts/api/
- x-auth-type: None

but when I curl https://mywso2host/javascripts/api/debug.js I get a 
404 - No matching resource found for given API Request

A curl to https://192.168.10.10/javascripts/api/debug.js (from mywso2host) works fine.

Comment: I [posted my own solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187504/wso2-how-to-create-custom-mediation-sequence-to-serve-static-content) by creating a custom mediation sequence for the In Flow.

Comment: See [my alternative post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187504/wso2-how-to-create-custom-mediation-sequence-to-serve-static-content) for the solution.

Comment: See my [alternative post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187504/wso2-how-to-create-custom-mediation-sequence-to-serve-static-content) for the solution.